# Create Slideshow images

Tags: image, blackberry, slideshow

I am newbie for Blackberry Application Programming.
I still learn about VerticalFieldManager and how to add Image.
Now, I can set header with logo after a weeks.
But today I have a problem about slideshow image.
I need to create slideshow image after header ( logo ) , I got the images from array
and I want put that image into 1 VerticalFieldManager below Header.

Can someone can help me, how to make it?
Thx

Comment: How do you want to show the images?  Are they full-screen?  Thumbnails?  How many images do you have to display?

Answer (score 0):

Use a PictureScrollField: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Picture_scroll_field_1204071_11.jsp